# Bug with Revival badge

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, revival-badge

Over on Pro Webmasters, I was just awarded the Revival badge for my answer here: [Bulletin board software with voting capability for each post](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/1965/bulletin-board-software-with-voting-capability-for-each-post/4905#4905)

But mine was not the first answer as you can see, so unless I'm mistaken I should not have got that badge. There were also some older "me too!" type answers that have been deleted, so perhaps that caused the bug, even though there is at least one remaining answer that is older.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yours is not the first answer ever, but it is the first answer *to get two upvotes*, which is what the Revival badge is [all about](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/badges/67/revival):

> Answered more than 30 days later **as first answer scoring 2 or more**.

Emphasis added.

Comment: Hmm, I guess you're right. I assumed that since it was introduced in the same blog post as the "no answers" tab, it meant the answer had to be the first actual answer.